# How to test a unhandledRejection / uncaughtException handler with jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have handlers for `unhandledRejection`s and `uncaughtException`s:

**bin.js**

```
['unhandledRejection', 'uncaughtException'].forEach(event => {
  process.on(event, err => logger.error(err));
});
```

Now I want to test them with `jest`:

**bin.test.js**

```
const bin = require('../bin');

test('catches unhandled rejections', async () => {
  const error = new Error('mock error');
  await Promise.reject(error);
  expect(logger.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
});

test('catches uncaught exceptions', () => {
  const error = new Error('mock error');
  throw error;
  expect(logger.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
});
```

But `jest` just tells me that there are errors in the tests:

> ● catches unhandled rejections
>
> ```
> mock error
>
>    8 | // https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5620
>    9 | test('catches unhandled rejections', async () => {
> > 10 |   const error = new Error('mock error');
>      |                 ^
>   11 |   await Promise.reject(error);
>   12 |   expect(logger.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
>   13 | });
>
>   at Object.<anonymous>.test (test/bin.test.js:10:17)
> ```
>
> ● catches uncaught exceptions
>
> ```
> mock error
>
>   14 |
>   15 | test('catches uncaught exceptions', () => {
> > 16 |   const error = new Error('mock error');
>      |                 ^
>   17 |   throw error;
>   18 |   expect(logger.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
>   19 | });
>
>   at Object.<anonymous>.test (test/bin.test.js:16:17)
> ```

is there a way to test this?

This might be related: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5620

Comment: I think this is doable but I need to know how logger gets built

Comment: @jcollum like this `const logger = winston.createLogger({/* ...some options */});`

Answer (score 5):

My test strategy is to install spy onto `process.on()` and `logger.error` methods using [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname). After doing this, these methods have no side effects. Then, you can test your code logic in an isolated environment.

Besides, there are a few things to note:

- You should spy the functions before `require('./bin')` statement. Because when you load the `bin.js` module, the code will be executed.
- You should use [jest.resetModules()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestresetmodules) in the `beforeEach` hook to resets the module registry - the cache of all required modules. Why? because `require()` caches its results. So, the first time a module is required, then its initialization code runs. After that, the cache just returns the value of `module.exports` without running the initialization code again. But we have two test cases, we want the code in module scope to be executed twice.

Now, here is the example:

`bin.js`:

```js
const logger = require('./logger');

['unhandledRejection', 'uncaughtException'].forEach((event) => {
  process.on(event, (err) => logger.error(err));
});
```

`logger.js`:

```js
const logger = console;

module.exports = logger;
```

`bin.test.js`:

```js
const logger = require('./logger');

describe('52493145', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('catches unhandled rejections', () => {
    const error = new Error('mock error');
    jest.spyOn(process, 'on').mockImplementation((event, handler) => {
      if (event === 'unhandledRejection') {
        handler(error);
      }
    });
    jest.spyOn(logger, 'error').mockReturnValueOnce();
    require('./bin');
    expect(process.on).toBeCalledWith('unhandledRejection', expect.any(Function));
    expect(logger.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
  });

  test('catches uncaught exceptions', () => {
    const error = new Error('mock error');
    jest.spyOn(process, 'on').mockImplementation((event, handler) => {
      if (event === 'uncaughtException') {
        handler(error);
      }
    });
    jest.spyOn(logger, 'error').mockReturnValueOnce();
    require('./bin');
    expect(process.on).toBeCalledWith('uncaughtException', expect.any(Function));
    expect(logger.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/52493145/bin.test.js
  52493145
    ✓ catches unhandled rejections (5 ms)
    ✓ catches uncaught exceptions (1 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 bin.js    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 logger.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.73 s, estimated 4 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/52493145

Answer (score -3):

putting it inside try catch will help:

const error = new Error('mock error');

try {

```
await Promise.reject(error);
```

}
catch(error){

```
   expect(logger.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
```

}

Comment: Thanks, butI want to explicitly check unhandled rejections and not catch them