# how to unit test uncaughtException and unhandledRejection in Nodejs using Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have built an error handler like this:

```js
const logger = require('./logger');

module.exports = () => {
  process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    logger.error(err.message, err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    throw err;
  });
};
```

Now I want to unit test this, mainly the first event listener. My current test looks like this:

```js
const logger = require('../../utils/logger');
require('../../utils/unhandledErrors')();

describe('Uncaught Exceptions', () => {
  it('should log the exception and exit the process', () => {
    process.exit = jest.fn();
    logger.error = jest.fn();
    jest.fn(() => {
      throw new Error('fake error');
    })();

    expect(logger.error).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(process.exit).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(process.exit).toBeCalledWith(1);
  });
});
```

The code above fails at throw new error line with no useful information logged to console by jest despite the --verbose flag.
Any suggestions on how to unit test such modules? I have looked through the link below but found nothing.
[How to test a unhandledRejection / uncaughtException handler with jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52493145/how-to-test-a-unhandledrejection-uncaughtexception-handler-with-jest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My test strategy is to install spy onto `process.on()`, `process.exit()` and `console.error` methods using [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname). After doing this, these methods have no side effects. Then, you can test your code logic in an isolated environment.

E.g.

`unhandledErrors.js`:

```js
module.exports = () => {
  process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    throw err;
  });
};
```

`unhandledErrors.test.js`:

```js
const unhandledErrors = require('./unhandledErrors');

describe('65386298', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should handle uncaughtException', () => {
    const mError = new Error('Server internal error');
    jest.spyOn(process, 'on').mockImplementation((event, handler) => {
      if (event === 'uncaughtException') {
        handler(mError);
      }
    });
    jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockReturnValueOnce();
    jest.spyOn(process, 'exit').mockReturnValueOnce();
    unhandledErrors();
    expect(process.on).toBeCalledWith('uncaughtException', expect.any(Function));
    expect(process.exit).toBeCalledWith(1);
    expect(console.error).toBeCalledWith('Server internal error');
  });

  it('should handle unhandledRejection', () => {
    const mError = new Error('dead lock');
    jest.spyOn(process, 'on').mockImplementation((event, handler) => {
      if (event === 'unhandledRejection') {
        handler(mError);
      }
    });
    expect(() => unhandledErrors()).toThrowError('dead lock');
    expect(process.on).toBeCalledWith('unhandledRejection', expect.any(Function));
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65386298/unhandledErrors.test.js
  65386298
    ✓ should handle uncaughtException (3 ms)
    ✓ should handle unhandledRejection (1 ms)

--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files           |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 unhandledErrors.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.201 s
```